# Accessing Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, cj

In the following code I am accessing the cookieCode in the `var MasterTmsUdo` but I am unable to access this variable.
Can anyone tell me how can I access this variable inside `var MasterTmsUdo`?

```
var cookieCode="True";
console.log(cookieCode);
var MasterTmsUdo = { 'CJ' : { 'CID': ' 897415', 'TYPE': '894', 'AMOUNT' : '35.00', 'OID' : "115", 'CURRENCY' : 'USD','FIRECJ' : cookieCode, } };
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a property of the `CJ` object, therefore you can access it via:

```
MasterTmsUdo.CJ.FIRECJ
```

Therefore you could have:

```
var cookieCode="True";
console.log(cookieCode);
var MasterTmsUdo = { 'CJ' : { 'CID': ' 897415', 'TYPE': '894', 'AMOUNT' : '35.00', 'OID' : "115", 'CURRENCY' : 'USD','FIRECJ' : cookieCode } };
console.log(MasterTmsUdo.CJ.FIRECJ);
```

Comment: I dont want to access the FIRECJ elements. I have to set the FIRECJ Value equal to cookieCode Which is javascript variable.How can i do that?

Comment: @user3480945 You are already passing a reference to `cookieCode` in your declaration.

Comment: but it is not take the value of cookieCode.It prints the as FIRECJ:cookieCode while it should be FIRECJ:"True" ?

Comment: @user3480945 See my update. If you run my code snippet do you not see True? NB I've also removed a trailing comma in your JSON object which may have been causing issues in certain browsers

Comment: I have a basic question why it is not print the value of cookieCode at FIRECJ:cookieCode ?

Comment: @user3480945 What script are you writing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Access the variable by using the following code:

```
var FireCJ = MasterTmsUdo['CJ']['FIRECJ'];
```

OR

```
var FireCJ = MasterTmsUdo.CJ.FIRECJ;
```

You can then alert or console.log the code and it will return the **string** "True". FireCJ can also be used in other code to make some IF statements for example

Small note: You can either use a boolean type (true or false) instead of a string type containing 'True'. 

IF statement with boolean:

```
if(FireCJ) {
    // TRUE
}
```

IF statement with your code:

```
if(FireCJ == 'True') {
    // TRUE
}
```